# Why is this integral equal to $1$? (VBIL)

Tags: probability, bayesian, expected-value, likelihood, variational-bayes

Let $p(y \mid \theta)$ be a likelihood and $\hat{p}_N(y \mid \theta)$ be an unbiased estimator of it.

In [VBIL](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.08621) they define $z = \log \hat{p}_N(y \mid \theta) - \log p(y\mid \theta)$ and call its density $g_N(z \mid \theta)$. Then they say the following expectation is equal to $1$
$$
\int e^z g_N(z \mid \theta) dz = 1
$$
Why is this the case? Of course I tried the following
$$
\frac{1}{p(y \mid \theta)} \int p(y \mid \theta) e^z g_N(z \mid \theta) dz = \frac{1}{p(y \mid \theta)}\int \hat{p}_N(y \mid \theta) g_N(z \mid \theta) dz
$$
but this doesn't lead anywhere as we are integrating with respect to $z$ so we can't use the unbiasedness property.

Comment: I think the randomness in the estimator $\hat p_N(y|\theta)$ is the one covered by the integration, ie$$\int \hat{p}_N(y \mid \theta) g_N(z \mid \theta) \text dz=\int z g_N(z \mid \theta) \text dz$$as $y$ and $\theta$ are fixed.

Comment: @Xi'an how would you formalize that? I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean that there's a bijection?